# Cookie based log in system

Tags: php, security

I am considering using a cookie-ip matching system to log in users automatically without them having to enter their login data if they are on a known system and their ip has not changed.

Is this policy decent or am I opening a major security hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ỉt can be a potential security problem in so far as some people use public machines. So make it optional. Also you need to consider that some machines use dynamic IP addressing. You proposed method will not work in this case.

But above all **DO NOT** store the password in the cookie.

Comment: I don't mind the method not working on some scenarios, I just want to provide it as an extra, not as the basic log in system. If it fails, they just go to the log in screen and enter their data. I also don't mind giving access to other users of the same machine access. I think it is the users responsibility to log out when using public machines. And of course, storing the password would be a security crime on my part.

Comment: Why not adopt the method that Yahoo (amongst others) use? Have a check box to keep you logged in. Then by default when the browser closes they are logged out.

Answer (score 1):

Just create "Logout" link, where you just before you delete their cookie, pick their e-mail and mail them link with a hash, that regenerates their cookie. So they can logout on public machines.

Sanitize cookie before processing through database.

Comment: logout button will delete the cookie and they will have to re enter the data. I'm just asking if this is a security hole. Cookies can be tampered. If someone can tamper ip as well, they might gain illegal access to my website.

Comment: Not if you store all the data before deleting the cookie. Send them link over e-mail to reset the cookie.
IP can be tampered just at Cookies, so you need better security (combining with e-mail checks can be it.

Answer (score 1):

That's, of course, a security hole since if the user login to your website and forget to logout, anyone using this computer (with the same account on the computer) will be able to login to your website.

Note that this problem also occurs for all website, only it's usually limited to the session lifetime.

Since that's how all websites work, I don't think this is a real security hole, but it definitely encourage users to be careless about security. It's a chair/keyboard interface security hole :P

As @Ed Heal is saying, do not store password in the cookie, store a random token instead which you'll save in the DB. The login process should check if the cookie stored in DB equals the one on the cookie.